# Opscenter 6.0.2 does not start

Tags: datastax, opscenter

I am trying to install new fresh cluster. I have trouble with opscenter 6.0.2. The opscenter doesnt start. I saw the problem in stackoverflow but enviroment is redhat. Since i dont have the experience to change anything in the post which has solution. I would be nice if someone help me to solve the problem for ubuntu.

```
2016-09-06 08:49:14,577 [opscenterd]  INFO: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./bin/twistd", line 64, in <module>
    run()
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 29, in run
    app.run(runApp, ServerOptions)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/application/app.py", line 617, in run
    runApp(config)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/scripts/twistd.py", line 25, in runApp
    _SomeApplicationRunner(config).run()
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/application/app.py", line 348, in run
    self.application = self.createOrGetApplication()
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/application/app.py", line 413, in createOrGetApplication
    application = getApplication(self.config, passphrase)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/application/app.py", line 424, in getApplication
    application = service.loadApplication(filename, style, passphrase)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/application/app.py", line 424, in getApplication
    application = service.loadApplication(filename, style, passphrase)
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/application/service.py", line 410, in loadApplication
    application = sob.loadValueFromFile(filename, 'application',
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/lib/py/twisted/persisted/sob.py", line 207, in loadValueFromFile
    eval(codeObj, d, d)
  File "bin/start_opscenter.py", line 1, in <module>
    from opscenterd import opscenterd_tap
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/jython/Lib/site-packages/opscenterd/opscenterd_tap.py", line 22, in <module>
  File "/usr/share/opscenter/jython/Lib/site-packages/opscenterd/LCMService.py", line 108, in start_lcm (MainThread)
```

Comment: I'm a developer of OpsCenter and can help you get going. We commonly run it under Ubuntu.

How are you trying to start OpsCenter? Is there a particular set of instructions you are following?

Can you paste the full log? There may be relevant output above the stacktrace that will help me figure out what's going wrong.

Comment: @elijah thanks to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38229653/opscenter-6-0-start-up-issue this link finally i solved my problem. Thank you for your attention.